# No encuentro falla en el While

Tags: python, vscode

estoy seguro de que me funciono una vez y luego ya no, si le movi algo sin darme cuanta no se lo que le movi, ayuda por favor, entra al while incluso si le pongo los caracteres correctos a la variable r

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
"""
Peirle 2 numeros al usuario y hacer todas las operadiones basicas de la calculadora
"""

```
n = int(input("Inserta 1er numero: "))
m = int(input("Inserta 2do numero: "))

print("Sumar: +\nRestar: - \nMultiplicar: *\nDividir: /")

r = input("Write an operation: ")

while r != "+" or r != "-" or r != "*" or r != "/":
    r = input("Write an operation: ")
else:
    if r == "+":
        print(f"El resultado de la suma es: {n+m}")
    elif r == "-":
        print(f"El resultado de la resta es: {n-m}")
    elif r == "*":
        print(f"El resultado de la multiplicacion es: {n*m}")
    elif r == "/" :
        print(f"El resultado de la division es: {n/m}")
```

Comment: while / else no tiene sentido. While es un bucle, mientras que else se pone tras un if

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' Cuidado, que python es muy raro! Sí que tiene una cláusula `else` para los bucles (tanto para `while` como para `for`) y se ejecuta si el bucle se ejecuta totalmente hasta llegar a su final, esto es, si se sale del bucle "normalmente". No se ejecuta el `else` si se sale del bucle con un `break `. En este caso por tanto no tiene mucho sentido el `else` ya que al no haber `break` dentro del `while` el `else`  se va a ejecutar siempre y por tanto perfectamente podría quitarse el `else` y desindentar todo lo que sigue.

Comment: @JM499 No pongas código como imagen. Hace imposible a otros usuarios probar a ejecutarlo para encontrar el problema. Por otro lado ¿cuál es el problema? Deberías describirlo en vez de obligar a que lo adivinemos.

Comment: @abulafia caramba, eso no lo sabía. Aunque pensándolo bien, me acuerdo ahora que try/except también lo tiene, luego `else` es más de lo que decía yo. Gracias!

Comment: @abulafia ya puse el codigo

Comment: Te ha faltado explicar también qué problema encuentras. De todas formas supongo que es que el bucle te pide una y otra vez la operación, y es que todos tus `or` deberían ser `and` (anda!! en la imagen está bien! ¿ves por qué hay que pegar el código?). Usando `or`  la condición del `while` sería siempre cierta y se repetiría siempre (puesto que cuando pones `+`, se cumplirá que es distinto de `-`, por ejemplo). Por otro lado leete lo que puse en el comentario sobre el `else` que puedes quitar.

Comment: @abulafia y podria escribirlo sin el r != x para cada and? despues del +?

Comment: algo como esto? while r != ("+" and  "-" and  "*" and "/")

Comment: por cierto, si puse el problema, esta al principio

Comment: No, la expresión que propones no es válida. Pero puedes hacer algo bastante más simple: `while r not in "+-*/"` que mira si el texto introducido en `r` no está en la cadena `"+-*/"`.

Comment: @abulafia Oka, muchisimas gracias, tratare de mejorar en la sintaxis de las preguntas para la proxima :) te agradezco mucho

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La clausula del `while` está mal escrita.

Lo que intentas es seguir en el `while` hasta que `r` sea una operación aritmética válida.

Hay varias formas de expresar esto. La más concisa es:

```
while r not in "+-*/":
   r =input("Operación:")
```

Aqui simplemente preguntamos si el cadena `r` es parte de la cadena que contiene las operaciones válidas.

Si quieres preguntar más trabajosamente, puedes hacer cada comparación por separado.

```
while r != '+' and r != '-' and r != '*' and r != '/':
    r =input("Operación:")
```

La pregunta en:

```
while r != '+' and '-' and '*' and '/':
```

dara `True` basado sólo cuando `r` sea `+`. Ahi hay cuatro condiciones lógicas separadas, unidas por `and`:

- `r != '+'` Que sera cierta cuando el usuario ingres `+`.
- `'-', '*' y '/'` Que siempre será ciertas, pues son literales distintos de `None` o `False`

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por tu respuesta :)